# How to decrease the time to go main controller after application is launched in iPhone 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My application has Splash Screen in which the image taken is Default.png. Splash screen has
        delay of 4 sec.The time taken to start the main Controller after launching the application is 
        10 sec in my Device.  How can I reduce the time to come to mainScreen after the application
        launch.

Can Anyone please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your app doing during initialisation?

Answer (score 0):

Profile using Instruments so that you understand why your app is taking so long to start. Try to avoid doing anything that's not absolutely necessary at launch, particularly those tasks that take the longest. Defer those tasks until they're actually needed, or move them to a background thread, or both. Jobs like downloading data can usually be done quite effectively in the background.